# How can I set a TTL value for items created with AWS AppSync mutation in a lambda function?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Is it possible to set the TTL value when I create an item with Appsync mutation in a lambda function? I noticed that  _deleted is set true and the _ttl field will be added in DynamoDB if I delete an item on Amplify studio. What if I want to create an item that only lives for 1 hour, then it will be automatically removed, how can I do that?

I took a look at the schema.graphql, the mutation input doesn't include the ttl field. What should I do? What is the correct way to create an item with a ttl value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply just add an extra field in your item as `ttl` or any other naming convention you like. When you create the item, set the value of `ttl` to 1 hr in the future, as a number type in epoch seconds.

Enable TTL on your DynamoDB table in the console for the attribute you created `ttl`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the ttl field to the model as you said and set it today 14:10 UTC-4 in epoch second.  However, the item is still existing in the table. I guess I have to wait for the next background process to have it removed. I'll give you an update later see if the item is deleted within 48 hours.